# I cannot seem to find a way to get a list of all the points of a ScatterPlotItem in Pyqtgraph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqtgraph

I am trying to access a list of all the SpotItems of a ScatterPlotItem in Pyqtgraph so as to manipulate them separately and change their properties, like their color or size, but so far I haven't found a way to go about it. I can access the point clicked by connecting the `sigClicked(self, points)` to a function, but I can't figure out how to get a list of all the points in the plot. I have tried the following:

```
scatter_plot = pyqtgraph.ScatterPlotItem(size=5)
data = scatter_plot.data

for i in data:
  scatter[i].setPen(pyqtgraph.mkPen(cosmetic=True, width=10.5, color=QtGui.QColor(210, 85, 173)), size=10)
```

This gives me an error:

```
'ScatterPlotItem' object does not support indexing
```

It looks like `scatter_plot.data` returns a list of the points' attributes and not points themselves. However this does not allow me to manipulate the properties directly. I can do something like  this:

```
for i in data:
  data[i][0] = 10
```

That will change the zeroeth element of the data array (which corresponds to the x value) into a value of 10. How can I change the pen and the brush of the SpotItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the SpotItems you must use the points() method:

```py
import random
import sys

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
    plt = view.addPlot()
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    y = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12]
    s = pg.ScatterPlotItem(x, y, size=10)
    plt.addItem(s)
    view.show()

    for pt in s.points():
        # random color
        color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))
        pt.setPen(
            pg.mkPen(cosmetic=True, width=10.5, color=color),
            size=10,
        )

    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
```